# How to set Buffered flv file metadata

Tags: c#, metadata, flv

I have flv file on my server. duration is 9 minutes.
I have to extract 30 seconds from this flv. I'm reading  the 30 second exact bytes from my source file and stream it to the client.
My problem is that when file is downloaded it, my gom player still showed that file is 9 minute but it has content of 30 seconds. how can I change this metadata during buffering.

My coding language is C#

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an editor for the metadata .. its command line , so shouldn't be a problem to run from the server .. http://www.buraks.com/flvmdi/
or if u wanna do it ur self .. the format specification is in here : http://osflash.org/flv

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 
I'm so close but still don't have success.
I've opened my flv file in hex editor to find duration bytes in metadata but had no luck. here is my screen shot http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/5554/capturefnw.png
any suggestions?